# LDAP authentication not working with IPv6 addresses/hosts

Tags: ldap, authentication, ipv6

I have an IPv6-only LAN. I tried to configure eJabberd (version 16.09) with LDAP authentication an it is not working. The error is:

```
2019-06-11 16:17:01.256 [error] <0.407.0>@eldap:connect_bind:1096 LDAP  connection failed:
** Server: armando.unimtz.mincin.cu:389
** Reason: nxdomain
** Socket options: [{packet,asn1},{active,true},{keepalive,true},   {send_timeout,30000},binary]
```

I've been searching with Google and found some tips, but nothing works. I share some fragments of relevant files:

## /etc/resolv.conf

```
domain unimtz.mincin.cu
search unimtz.mincin.cu
nameserver ::1
```

## /etc/ejabberd/ejabberd.yml

```
...
auth_method:
  - ldap
ldap_servers:
  - "armando.unimtz.mincin.cu"
...
```

## /etc/ejabberd/inetrc

```
{lookup,["file","native"]}.
{file, resolv, "/etc/resolv.conf"}.
{inet6, true}.
```

Can anyone tell me what's going on and how to solve this?

Comment: Have you tried manually entering in the IPv6 address as [2001:db8]:389?
does `dig armando.unimtz.mincin.cu AAAA` give any results? does this IP match your ldap server?

Comment: I have fully control over the internal domain and I can resolve perfectly everything. I can resolve with 'dig' and 'nslookup' and do 'ping' to that name.

Comment: see bug, are you running 18.06 or newer?
https://blog.process-one.net/ejabberd-18-06/

https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=895692

Comment: I'm using 16.09 which is in the stable branch of Debian GNU/Linux repo. Thanks. I read that I must to upgrade to +18.06. I don't see how to give you +1. Thanks.

Comment: @Leinier Buster, the next Debian stable release, is to be released in a couple of days, July 6th 2019. Maybe that's an option for you. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

LDAP tries to bind / connect to `armando.unimtz.mincin.cu` which is not possible, as the error indicates: NXDOMAIN, which means that the domain doesn't exist. Probably, it's worth checking your DNS and/or the `hosts` file(s) in use.

Comment: I know what that error mean and I know everybody will take the path of the DNS server, but, the DNS is fully working. I think eJabberd is trying to resolve the A record of that DNS name, but, obviously that doesn't exist because my network is IPv6-only. I tried to use the IPv6 address and didn't work.

Comment: Well, do a tcpdump or something on the client.  See what DNS requests it sends.

Comment: I think I will solve nothing with that but to know what kind of DNS request eJabberd is doing. Seem that anybody is not using eJabberd in an IPv6-only scenario. If somebody knows how to solve this, post the solution, please.Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug ([bug report](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=895692)) and is fixed in a newer version. Please upgrade to version 18.06 ([release notes](http://blog.process-one.net/ejabberd-18-06)) or newer.